# Microsoft cognitive SDK(Speech to text) TimeoutException: com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.SpeechRecognizer.finalize()

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services

`recognizeOnceAsync()` method is used for speech recogniton. its work fine. (For cancelling the request `stopContinuousRecognitionAsync()`) . its work fine, but some times its throw below `exception`

**java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:**

`com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.SpeechRecognizer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.carbon_javaJNI.delete_Recognizer(Native Method)
        at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.Recognizer.delete(SourceFile:32)
        at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.SpeechRecognizerBase.delete(SourceFile:37)
        at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.SpeechRecognizer.delete(SourceFile:37)
        at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.SpeechRecognizer.finalize(SourceFile:26)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to `implementation 'com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech:client-sdk:1.30.0'`

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the issue (do you have a source?) and how to do this?